# What is the best use of Warzone Commendations (for PVP purposes) after reaching Battlemaster (Valor Rank 60)?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

While I understand the word "best" may make the question a little subjective, but from a pure PVP perspective what would be the best use of these commendations after you get to rank 60/buy all your gear?

I consider the mounts flavour items that don't do anything PVP wise (I do plan on getting them eventually though).

[Healing](http://www.torhead.com/item/9jLTZb9/warzone-medpac) and [Expertise](http://www.torhead.com/item/OwKe18/warzone-expertise-adrenal) adrenals are 10 WZ commendations each and I use them pretty liberally (at least the healing one), and that is a good use of them.

At the moment I have been spending 70 WZ commendations and buying the [Black Market Preimum PVP Bag](http://www.torhead.com/item/6qkcNeg/black-market-premium-pvp-box) They contain anywhere between 2-4 of each adrenal and a Bind on Equip level 45 green item that can be sold either on the GTN or just to a vendor for credits. The risk on the box is that you may or may not get the same number of adrenals as if you had just bought them 10 for 1.

What I am wondering is/are there better things to spend the WZ commendations on that will further PVP objectives?

Comment: I assume you mean Bind on Equip (_not_ Bind on Pickup) if you're selling the bag contents on the GTN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold on to them next patch Tuesday you will be able to buy Battle-Master Commendations

[Patch 1.1.5 Notes](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?p=3077822#edit3077822)

Answer (score 1):

> What I am wondering is/are there better things to spend the WZ commendations on that will further PVP objectives?

Further? At this stage of the game there isn't, until they add more items/gear. What you're doing is about as good as it'll be.

If you want to optimize the number of adrenals, buy them separately (70 wz can buy 7 adrenals instead of just 2-4), if you want/need the extra credits then the Premium bag is good enough.

Comment: Already stated in my question that I have all the gear. You can only reach rank 60 at level 50 anyway.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I said 2-4 of each type, not 2-4 of one. Sometimes I end up with 7 plus the green, sometimes only 5 and the green.